# Given $\exists x.\lnot p(x)$, use the Fitch System to prove $\lnot \forall x.p(x)$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

This is what I've come up with so far, but I'm stuck at step 11:

\begin{align}
&(1)\quad \exists x.\lnot p(x) & \text{Premise}\\
&(2)\quad \lnot p(x) & \text{Assumption}\\ 
& (3)\quad \forall x.p(x) &\text{Assumption}\\
&(4)\quad p(x) & \text{Universal Elimination: 3}\\
& (5)\quad \forall x.p(x)\rightarrow p(x) & \text{Implication Introduction: 3, 4}\\
& (6)\quad \forall x.p(x) & \text{Assumption}\\
& (7)\quad \lnot p(x) & \text{Reiteration: 2}\\
& (8) \quad \forall x.p(x) \rightarrow \lnot p(x) & \text{Implication Introduction: 6, 7}\\
& (9) \quad \lnot \forall x.p(x) & \text{Negation Introduction: 5, 8}\\
& (10) \quad \lnot p(x) \rightarrow \lnot \forall x.p(x) & \text{Implication Introduction: 2, 9}\\
& (11) \quad \forall x.(\lnot p(x) \rightarrow \lnot \forall x.p(x)) & \text{Universal Introduction: 10}
\end{align}

I figured Existential Elimination would be step 12, but all I get is    $\lnot p([c6])$.

Any help? Thank you.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format mathematics on this site. I added it to your post - you can edit the post to see the syntax I used, and you can find a tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What does $\lnot p([c6])$ mean?

Comment: And can you clarify what your rule of existential elimination says? If it is [this one](https://notepad.mmakowski.com/existential%20elimination), then I agree you can apply the rule to (1) and (11) to get $\lnot \forall x. p(x)$.

Comment: Hi Alex, this is the rule of EE we've been given in this course: Existential Elimination
∃ν.φ[ν]
φ[[τ]]

And yes I tried to apply to (1) and (11) and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$
Try proof by contradiction, work backward that we will need
$$\fitch{1.\exists x(\neg P(x))}{\fitch{2.~\forall x(P(x))}{3.\\4.\\5.\\6.~\bot\hspace{20ex}\text{???}}\\7.\neg\forall x(P(x))\hspace{15ex}\text{$\neg$ Intro}~2-6}$$
Observe that from assumption we have $\exists x(\neg P(x))$, clearly will contradict with $\forall x(P(x))$.

**Answer:**

$$\fitch{1.\exists x(\neg P(x))}{\fitch{2.~\forall x(P(x))}{\fitch{3.~\boxed{a}~\neg P(a)}{4.~P(a)\hspace{13.5ex}\forall\text{ Elim}~2\\5.~\bot\hspace{16ex}\bot\text{ Intro}~3,4}\\6.~\bot\hspace{20ex}\text{$\exists$ Elim }1,3-5 }\\7.\neg\forall x(P(x))\hspace{15ex}\text{$\neg$ Intro}~2-6}$$

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: I'm trying that way but I still get stuck at step 5:
 1. EX:~p(X)  Premise
 2. AX:p(X)    Assumption
 3. ~P(X)      Assumption
 4. p(X)        Universal Elimination: 2
 5. ~P(X) => p(X)  Implication Introduction: 3, 4
 6. ~p([c9])         Existential Elimination: 1

Comment: @Nag I see, you seems like using the fitch system from stanford.edu, check my update.

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much!

Comment: @Nag - If you think this answer is useful, you can upvote and accept it.